# Chartjs adapter for Dayjs CDN: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: javascript, npm, chart.js, cdn, dayjs

I'm using the CDN for the adapter for Chartjs to utilize Dayjs (chartjs-adapter-dayjs-4) and I'm getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`

I need to be able to use the CDN link for the Javascript that I'm writing, but I can't control the code in the CDN to define `process`.

Why won't this work and how can I fix it? Here's a link to the CDN source I'm using:

https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/chartjs-adapter-dayjs-4

And here is the line from my HTML linking to it:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-dayjs-4/dist/index.min.js"></script>`

Note: I'm not using Node.js

Changing the version doesn't seem to work, neither does switching from "Default" to "ESM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking through the files that are in the build it seems like you will need to use the following link instead as the source: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-dayjs-4@1.0.4/dist/chartjs-adapter-dayjs-4.cjs.production.min.js`

Comment: This gives me yet another error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at chartjs-adapter-dayjs-4.cjs.production.min.js:1:90`. It's worth noting that `require` shows up a number of times after that line as well. Is this fixable? I find it hard to believe that a package like this would be put in a CDN while being this difficult to work with.